# Change number of days to months/years

Tags: php

So I have this code that is responsible to display how many days ago a user joined a website:

```
<?php echo sprintf(__('Joined %s ago','PricerrTheme'),$joined); ?>
```

However, what it shows now is, for example, "**Joined 150 days ago.**"

What I want to make it display is, for example, "**Joined 5 months ago.**"

It should be a small edit to that code I posted above. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please take a look at this https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that doesn't really help me. I don't get it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime` ([look here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)) PHP Class and make code like this:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P'.$joined.'D');
$days = $interval->format('%d'); // This will convert in days
$months = $interval->format('%m'); // This will convert in months
$years = $interval->format('%y'); // This will convert in years
```

To decide which of these you need, you can use mathematic conditions, like:

```
if($joined / 30 > 0) {
    if($joined / 30 > 12) {
        // Show years
    } 
    // Show months
} else {
    // Show days
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the complete reply. But unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to apply this. I tried a few things with your code that sort of made sense to me, but each time it broke the site. So I implemented it wrong surely.

Comment: Show me how you implemented the code and, probably, I will help you :)